# из python в java

Tags: java, python

Помогите конвертировать код из python в java

```
def main():

    username = input("Please enter your name, and I'll convert it to a number: ")
    usernumber = 0  # initialize
    for character in username:
        # convert to lower case...
        # convert to ordinal form
        # subtract so that a = 1
        # add to total
        if character != " ":
            usernumber = usernumber + ord(character.lower()) - 96
    print(usernumber)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Есть код где вы пытались перевести это, но у вас что то не получилось?

Comment: цикл можно записать: `sum(ord(c) - ord('a') + 1 for c in username.casefold() if not c.isspace())` Для не-ascii букв, не ясно зачем `'a'` вычитать. Может вы просто хотите: `hash(username.casefold())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В `java 8` это может выглядеть как-то так:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int userNumber = getUserName()
                .chars()
                .filter(c -> c != ' ')
                .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                .map(c -> c - 92)
                .sum();
        System.out.println(userNumber);
    }

    private static String getUserName() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name, and I'll convert it to a number: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();

        return userName;
    }
}
```

**Если более старая версия, то метод `main` можно заменить на такой:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userNumber = 0;
    for (char character : getUserName().toCharArray()) {
        if (character != ' ') {
            userNumber += Character.toLowerCase(character) - 92;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(userNumber);
}
```